# How to make sure random string in django python model will unique

Tags: python, django

I have a question with the random string in python django.

I have created a django model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            str_ran = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            slug = ""
            for i in range(5) :
                slug += random.choice(str_ran)
            self.slug = slug
            super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But sometimes that's have some error because the slug field is not unique by python random isn't random a unique string.

What should i do?
Do you have some recommend for random these string to make sure it will be unique?

Comment: the builtin uuid library is generally used to make "unique" string identifiers ... (although you still maybe able to get duplicates, so put it in a try except that picks a new random slug)... with your code there are only 11.8 million possible combos... what happens when you have 11.9 million entries?

Comment: seeking uniqueness of random, use `shuffle` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create uniq index in database and cache errors when you write to database and get collisions
2. you can use (UUID + slag). UUID is generated based on current time, it allows to garanti uniqueness
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use uuid instead of random.

[Python's uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module provides an implementation compliant with [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122.html), to generate unique identifiers:

```
import uuid

slug = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

If you want to avoid the dashes (`-`) you can also use the hexadecimal representation:

```
slug = uuid.uuid4().hex
```